# Deleting files using ftp

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

I have developed a shell script to copy the files from source to destination and simultaneously to delete the copied files in source. I can copy the files but the files cannot be deleted in source side.

```
files='ls filename'
for file in $files
do
ftp -vn $hostname <<EOFD
  quote USER $username
  quote PASS $password
binary
 cd $start_dir
 rm -rf $file
quit
EOFD
done
```

- I got errors as 'No such files or directories found'
- By putting ftp outside the forloop also i got error as 'invalid command'
- I also tried in ssh but it prompting for username and password

Answer (score 0):

```
files=`ls filename`
```

Put backticks, not simple quotes around the command to get its output.

*I also tried in ssh but it prompting for username and password* - check **[SSH-Login without password](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting FTP commands using input stream directly to `ftp` is usually a bad idea: it lacks any error handling, it can go totally wrong and you have no chance to control it. If you have any chance to use saner command-line client, such as `lftp`, `curl` or a similar scriptable one.

Also, it's a very bad idea to iterate over files using

```
files=`ls files`
for file in $files
```

A slightly better solution is:

```
for file in *
```

but it doesn't scale: if `*` (or `ls` output) would expand more than command line buffer, it will fail. A fairly scalable solution is something like:

```
find . | while read file do
  do_something_with $file
done
```

...and yet it's not probably what you want. In fact, if you just want to transfer files from source to destination and then delete files at source, you can just use `lftp` with `mput` command and `-E` option to delete file after transfer, or something similar with `rsync --remove-source-files`.

Answer (score 0):

Full-proof solution:

Replace the line

```
`rm -rf $file`
```

with

```
`!rm -rf $file`
```

This is because, at that place in the code you are on the ftp console until the `EOFD` string is reached, so to run any command on local system(source), you need `!` to be prefixed.

Best way to test is manually executing the commands. Here's what I have tested:

```
mtk4@laptop:~$ ftp XXX.XXX.XXX
Connected to static-XX-XX-XX-XX.XXXXXX.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 07:52. Server port: 21.
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (XXXXXX.XXX:XXX): XXXXXXX 
331 User XXXXXXX OK. Password required
Password:
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> lcd test/
Local directory now /home/mtk4/test
ftp> pwd
257 "/" is your current location
ftp> !pwd
/home/mtk4/test
ftp> !ls
sample.txt
ftp> !rm sample.txt 
ftp> !ls
ftp> bye
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
mtk4@laptop:~$
```

---

Or another solution,

use the same for loop again, after the complete ftp is done to iterate over the same set of files and delete them.